# Moving in direction of gradient orientation in an image

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project where I need to find end points of a line. Through some progressing I get some points on the image colored blue as shown in the image attached. Using these blue seed points I want move along the line until I reach the end point.

However, I am unable to think how to code so that I can move along the line without offset. Please note that the while line is only pixel wide.

I just need some help perhaps some pseudocode or algorithm that can get me started.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find a path of only white pixels between blue points?

Comment: please post an image and not a screen shot.

Comment: How do you define the blue points? Are the white points 4-connected or 8-connected? Have you tried labeling (`bwlabel`) of the white points excluding the blue ones?

Comment: I dont think details about how the blue points are obtained is important. The important problem is that I want to move starting at each of the blue points and move along the line until I find the line endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried [bwlabel](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) as @Shai suggested?

Comment: Why you have deleted previous question?

Comment: you can maintain a set of visited pixels and only visit neighboring (white) pixels if they are not in the set of visited. if you have no non visited neighboring pixels you are at the end of the line (assuming no loops, which can be handled as well...)

Comment: @RosaGronchi - You are describing a graph traversal algorithm, which I have linked as a duplicate as I have already answered this in the past.  Good job in suggesting that :)

Comment: @user1965914 A classic breadth-first search should work.  I've linked you to an appropriate duplicate. BTW, you don't need to do line tracing.  What you can do is search for every pixel that is white that has only two pixels within a 3 x 3 neighbourhood. As such, you could convolve your image with a 3 x 3 mask of ones, and locate those locations that have an output of 2.  However, looking at your question, you only want to find end points for a subset of your traces. As such, use the blue points as seeds, run BFS, then the resulting traces that are marked, use the above convolution algorithm.